# What are possible ways to access Amazaon S3 data if S3 outage happens?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can some one help me in understanding the S3 outage usecase here.

The probability of S3 outage is very less, but in case if this happens, what are the ways we can access data that sits in S3.

I know that there is one possibility, that is cross region replication, that works for new files, that I am going to put in my s3 bucket, if I enable it now. What happen to old files, I know if I go and upload all those historical files also to the other region, then it works.

Then again the same question, if both the regions went down, then what?

I am sure others would have thought of this. Any inputs on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Protecting Data in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html):

> Objects are redundantly stored on multiple devices across multiple facilities in an Amazon S3 region. To help better ensure data durability, Amazon S3 PUT and PUT Object copy operations synchronously store your data across multiple facilities before returning SUCCESS. Once the objects are stored, Amazon S3 maintains their durability by quickly detecting and repairing any lost redundancy.
>
> ...
>
> - Backed with the [Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement](http://aws.amazon.com/s3-sla/)
> - Designed to provide 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of objects over a given year
> - Designed to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities

So, if you're still not happy with all those statements, how can you access your data in an outage?

If your data is **in only one region**, and the region is not accessible, then your data is not accessible. Note, however, that an external network connectivity problem could prevent *access to Amazon S3*, yet Amazon S3 might still be accessible from Amazon EC2 instances in the same region.

**Cross-region replication** will copy your data to another Amazon S3 region. It requires versioning to be activated. To copy any files that exist prior to activating cross-region replication, use the `sync` command in the [AWS Command-Line Utility (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), eg:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket1/folder s3://bucket2/folder
```

Each AWS region operates independently, so the possibility of multiple regions suffering outages would presumably be even less likely.

If you are feeling particularly paranoid, you could copy your data to another cloud provider (Azure, Google, Rackspace, etc). There are tools that can assist:

- [CloudBerry Cloud Migrator](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/cloud-migrator.aspx)
- [AzureCopy](https://kpfaulkner.wordpress.com/azurecopyrelease/)
- ...and no doubt many more!

Comment: A very detailed explanation. These inputs are very much valuable to me.